# $(window).focus() runs twice for each focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not sure why this happens and I would love to get an explanation.

Using jquery's `focus` method I bind to the window focus event.
This is a working example (copy paste into a html file and open in a browser. Doesn't work in jsfiddle or jsbin, for some reason)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head><script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script></head>

<body>
    <p1>Here:</p1>
    <div id="here" >Why</div>
</body>
<script>
    $(window).load(function() {
        $(window).focus(function() {console.log("focus");});
        $(window).blur(function() {console.log("blur");});
    });
</script>
</html>
```

When the browser regains focus the function runs twice and 'focus` is printed into the console twice. 
Any idea why this happens?

The end goal, btw, is to stop a timer from running whenever the user leaves the browser to an app or another tab.

**UPDATE**

Running on the latest (dev) version of chrome. I'll test it on firefox and write if it's different there.

**UPDATE 2**
Interesting fact - Doesn't happen on firefox. Maybe its a bug with chrome.

Comment: This works for me. Which browser are you using?

Comment: @PhilBooth Chrome (Updated the question)

Comment: @Derek As I've written - I'm trying to see if the browser is in focus not #here

Comment: i think maybe it's the console itself. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this same problem. My fix for this was using lodash's `debounce()` function (https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce). This was my fix:

```
var debouncedFocus = _.debounce(() => {
  console.log('focussed');
}, 250, {leading: true, trailing: false});

$(window).on('focus', debouncedFocus);
```

Answer (score 1):

live() has been deprecated. Use on() instead.

```
$(window).on("focus", function(){ alert("focus!"); });
```

---

<strike>You could try using the live() function.</strike>

<strike>$(window).live("focus", function(){ alert("focus!"); });</strike>

Comment: The ``live()`` method is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7. Use the ``on()`` method instead: ``$(document).on("focus", function(){ console.log("focus!"); });``. See http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: But isn't the OP using v1.6? In that case `live` should be fine right?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `load()` is called twice? You can register these events without `.load()`. Try this:

```
<script>
    $(window).focus(function() {console.log("focus");});
    $(window).blur(function() {console.log("blur");});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Which browser ? Seems to run fine for me.

As a precaution, you can use a javascript variable to make it run only once.

```
<script>
    var isFocused = false;    
    $(window).load(function() {
        $(window).focus(function() {
           if(isFocused)
                return; 
           console.log("focus");
           isFocused = true;
        });

        $(window).blur(function() {
         console.log("blur");
         isFocused = false;
       });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're simultaneously using Underscore, you can use the `_.debounce()` method to clamp down repeated events to a single event.